# HTML/RTF string in to RTF file

Tags: html, rtf, text-parsing, file-conversion

Does anybody know how to insert some formatted text string into some RTF file?
I am able to insert any plain text into an RTF file (to any place in document I want), but not formatted strings.

I know that when such string is added to RTF file, then also some RTF heading has to be updated. And here is a problem. I need to find out what shall be placed in RTF heading and in which exactly place. Maybe there is some ready solution. So far I cannot find it anywhere.
Normally I work with Java, but the problem is not necessary related to any language.

Answer (score 0):

They talk about using a valid headder, in the [.rtf specifications](http://www.biblioscape.com/rtf15_spec.htm#Heading6). I hope this will help you to get a valid format result.

Plain text in .rtf files, without any valid "formatting syntax", will not return any other result than the given plain text.

Another way, to get a neat rich text formatted document, is by using an .rtf editor or some .rtf compiler for the programming language you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of dealing with the rtf property, you can use the Text property. Set the cursor to where you want to insert text. Then paste formatted text from another richtext box, or paste normal text and change its formatting.